# Android : Calendar provider -> How to add non-repeating calendar event (all day or with some start and duration)?

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I spend a few hours by trying to add calendar event into primary calendar using Calendar provider but without luck.

For example:

```
public void pushEventtoCalendar2(Activity curActivity, Context ctx) {
        try {
            ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, 1451776653);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "TEST");
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "DESC");

            TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());

            // default calendar
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);

            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL="
                    + 1451949453);
            //for one hour
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DURATION, "+P1H");

            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);

            // insert event to calendar
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ctx, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                Logger.d("NOT IMPL");
                return;
            }
            Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

            long eventId = new Long(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            Logger.d(String.valueOf(eventId));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.e(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Could somebody provide working example which is insert event into the given Calendar please?

I tried to found something on examples which i found on internet but none from them was not working for me.

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CalendarContract.Events](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html), there is a list of required fields for adding a new event.

Also be aware that the timestamps are in milliseconds, not in seconds. Your example event will be somewhere in 1970.

The following values will insert an one hour event at the current time into the calendar having the id `1`.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, now);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, now + 3600*1000 /* one hour later */);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "TEST");
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "DESC");
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
// default calendar
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Please note that there might be no calendar having the id `1`. You should look up existing calendars first (make sure you only look up writable calendars).

To insert an all-day event make sure `DTSTART` and `DTEND` are divisible by 24*3600*1000 (i.e. the number of milliseconds of a regular day) and also set `ALL_DAY` to `1`.

Don't use `DURATION`, that's only for recurring events.

#### Update:

I've added two more lines to complete the example. I've just tested this code. The given example works for me and does exactly what it's supposed to do.

Make sure the calendar you write to exists and is visible.

Also make sure your `AndroidManifest.xml` has the following entries:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
```

If you're testing in an emulator or your device is rooted you can verify the existence of the event by running the following commands on a shell on the device (or emulator):

```
cd /data/data/com.android.providers.calendar/databases/
sqlite3 calendar.db --line "select * from events where title='TEST' and description='DESC'"
```

For the sake of completeness, this is what the command returns on my Android 5.1 emulator (before the event has been synced):

```
                  _id = 18172
             _sync_id = 
                dirty = 1
             mutators = com.example.calendartest
           lastSynced = 0
          calendar_id = 1
                title = TEST
        eventLocation = 
          description = DESC
           eventColor = 
     eventColor_index = 
          eventStatus = 
   selfAttendeeStatus = 0
              dtstart = 1452004529497
                dtend = 1452008129497
        eventTimezone = Europe/Amsterdam
             duration = 
               allDay = 0
          accessLevel = 0
         availability = 0
             hasAlarm = 0
hasExtendedProperties = 0
                rrule = 
                rdate = 
               exrule = 
               exdate = 
          original_id = 
     original_sync_id = 
 originalInstanceTime = 
       originalAllDay = 
             lastDate = 1452008129497
      hasAttendeeData = 0
      guestsCanModify = 0
guestsCanInviteOthers = 1
   guestsCanSeeGuests = 1
            organizer = test@example.com
          isOrganizer = 
              deleted = 0
     eventEndTimezone = 
     customAppPackage = 
         customAppUri = 
              uid2445 = 
           sync_data1 = 
           sync_data2 = 
           sync_data3 = 
           sync_data4 = 
           sync_data5 = 
           sync_data6 = 
           sync_data7 = 
           sync_data8 = 
           sync_data9 = 
          sync_data10 =
```

Calendar `1` is a test calendar that's owned by `test@example.com`.

Comment: Thank You for reply. I get list of all available calendars with their ID's and inserted event into selected calendar. No exception has been thrown but event is still not displayed in calendar on the device.  Could You please test Your example on Your device?

Comment: Thanks for update but Sqlite3 query still returns empty results.

Comment: Do you run the code in the emulator or on a device? In the latter case what kind of device? Which Android version?
What account type does the calendar you're writing to have?
Also, are you sure your code is ever executed? Did you try to step through your code or Log the values?
It your code published, like on GitHub, so I can look at it?